# Pyinstaller doesn't recognise glob.glob to iterate through files?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a script that runs through files in a folder which I am trying to turn into an executable file (to share with coworkers) using PyInstaller (on a Mac and using python 3 if that matters).

When run in the interpreter as python code words fine. I use

```
file_list = []
for my_file in glob.glob('*.txt'): 
file_list.append(my_file) 
file_list.sort()  
print (file_list)
```

Which returns `[file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt]`

However, when I run the PyInstaller created file in the same folder (i.e. the one containing the .txt files) I get `[]` indicating that there are no files in the list.  Other than that the code appears to execute successfully so there are no other error messages to track down.

Does Pyinstaller have problems using `glob.glob()` if so has anyone successfully made Pyinstaller executables which iterate through files in a folder?

Comment: You can replace the first three lines with `file_list=glob.glob('*.txt')`. Less code - fewer chances to make a mistake.

Comment: Thanks, yes thats tidier - same issue remains however

Comment: any chance you solved this?